# Divide long table into two parts.

Tags: tables, longtable

The result of the code below is a long table which doesn't fit on a page. I want to break it into two parts but using longtable and \pagebreak makes the table disoriented and doesn't divide it into two parts. Any solutions would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{> 
{\centering\raggedright}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Global parameters HYDRO\_FT-2D}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} 
{@{}L{2.5cm}L{2.5cm}L{1.5cm}X@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c} 
{\textbf{Parameters\hspace{1em}}} & & \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
\textbf{Original} & \textbf{English translation} & \textbf{Used value} & \textbf{Definition} \\

\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}

Stofftransport- formel & Sediment transport fromula & MPM & To select the formula fro computing sediment transport. \\

Rauheitsermit-tlung & Roughness determination & a & This option shows the way in which roughness could be calculated. a = $\theta_c_r \quad \& \quad k_b$ (by default from \texttt{SMS}). \\

Schubspannun-gsschwankun-gen & Shear stress fluctuations & Off & To select whether the shear stress fluctuations will be considered or not. \\

$\theta\textsubscript{cr}$ &  & 0.047 & Critical Shields parameter \\

SCG\textsubscript{Formel}  &  & 1 & Scaling factor for sediment transport formula (equation \ref{eq:MPM}) \\

CF\textsubscript{Quergef\"alle}  & & 0 & Coefficient $c_f_\theta$ for consideration of the transport direction on inclined surfaces \\

A\textsubscript{r} & & 8 & Coefficient $A_r$ for consideration of river curves \\

SCFG & & 1 & Scaling factor for the additional acceleration of the calculation process \\

DZ\textsubscript{max}  & & 0.05 m & Parameters for the maximum allowed riverbed change during one time step\\

\tau\textsubscript{max} & & 500 N/m\textsuperscript{2} & Parameter for the maximum allowed bottom shear stress\\

c\textsubscript{max} & & 100 kg/s & Parameter for the maximum allowed sediment concentration\\

Sc\textsubscript{t} & & \num{0.70} & Turbulent Schmidt number\\

pal und pul & & 1 and 4 & Parameter for controlling riverbed layers\\

\rho\textsubscript{s} & & 2650 kg/m\textsuperscript{3} & Sediment density\\

n\textsubscript{p} & & \num{0.36} & Porosity\\

\phi & & 37 \degree & Internal friction angle for underwater material\\

Y\textsubscript{cr} & & 37 \degree& Internal friction angle for dry material\\

NF & & \num{8} and in single grain variant 1& Number of sediment fractions\\

d\textsubscript{i,m} & & - & Average size of used sediment fractions\\

\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:globalparametershydroFT}
\end{table}
```

Comment: long table is not intended to be inside float environment `table`. for start remove it and table will in case that it is longer than one page automatically break into two parts.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the documentation of `xltabular` or `longtable` for repeating a header. Run with `xelatex/lualatex` or load package `textcomp` for `\textdegree`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,xltabular,booktabs,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}L{2.5cm}L{2.5cm}L{1.5cm}X@{}}
\caption{Global parameters HYDRO\_FT-2D\label{tab:globalparametershydroFT}}\\\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}\quad} & & \\\cmidrule(r){1-2}
\textbf{Original} & \textbf{English translation} & \textbf{Used value} & \textbf{Definition}\\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
Stofftransport- formel & Sediment transport fromula & MPM & To select the formula fro 
        computing sediment transport. \\
Rauheitsermittlung & Roughness determination & a & This option shows the way in which 
        roughness could be calculated. a = $\theta_{c_r} \quad \& \quad k_b$ 
        (by default from \texttt{SMS}). \\
Schubspannungsschwankungen & Shear stress fluctuations & Off & To select whether the 
        shear stress fluctuations will be considered or not. \\
$\theta^{\text{cr}}$ &  & 0.047 & Critical Shields parameter \\
SCG\textsubscript{Formel}  &  & 1 & Scaling factor for sediment transport formula (equation 
        \ref{eq:MPM}) \\
CF\textsubscript{Quergef\"alle}  & & 0 & Coefficient $c_{f_\theta}$ for consideration of the 
        transport direction on inclined surfaces \\
A\textsubscript{r} & & 8 & Coefficient $A_r$ for consideration of river curves \\
        SCFG & & 1 & Scaling factor for the additional acceleration of the calculation process \\
DZ\textsubscript{max}  & & 0.05 m & Parameters for the maximum allowed riverbed change 
        during one time step\\      
$\tau^\text{max}$ & & 500 N/m\textsuperscript{2} & Parameter for the maximum allowed 
        bottom shear stress\\       
c\textsubscript{max} & & 100 kg/s & Parameter for the maximum allowed sediment concentration\\
Sc\textsubscript{t} & & \num{0.70} & Turbulent Schmidt number\\     
pal und pul & & 1 and 4 & Parameter for controlling riverbed layers\\       
$\rho^{\text{s}}$ & & 2650 kg/m\textsuperscript{3} & Sediment density\\     
n\textsubscript{p} & & \num{0.36} & Porosity\\      
$\phi$ & & 37 \textdegree & Internal friction angle for underwater material\\       
Y\textsubscript{cr} & & 37 \textdegree& Internal friction angle for dry material\\      
NF & & \num{8} and in single grain variant 1& Number of sediment fractions\\        
d\textsubscript{i,m} & & - & Average size of used sediment fractions\\
\bottomrule 
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textdegree` seems to be undefined in your example. Maybe add `textcomp` or a similar package?

Comment: Yes, but only if you run `(pdf)latex`. In this case you need  `\usepackage{textcomp}`. I _always_ prefer `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: OK, if you don't like `textcomp`, could you please add some other definition to make your code compilable? Or remove the problematic rows? It's current state seems to confuse users: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459767/any-ideas-on-how-this-table-could-be-made-better-looking/459771?noredirect=1#comment1162377_459771